# Как сделать проверку на добавления класса?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда добавляется определенный класс к определенному блоку, добавлять другой класс к определенному блоку.

```
if ($("#block_for_scroll").hasClass("style"))
{
    $('body').addClass("111")
}
```

Вот так думал, но не работает. Просто первый класс добавляется при скролле и нужно после добавления первого класса добавить другой. Как это реализовать?

Comment: скорее метод is() который возвращает boollean

Answer (score 1):

`hasClass` метод фильтрации, вам же нужен метод возвращающий boolean - `is()`.

```js
$(function() {
  if ($('#block_for_scroll').is('.style')) {
    $('body').addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #3c3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="block_for_scroll" class="style"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Не работает, на body не вешается класс, у меня добавляется класс при скролле, и нужно сделать так, что когда первый класс добавился при скролле, другой добавился на body

Comment: @Юзер что не работает? Это был пример, исправил с добавлением класса боди.